# Clicking an element in selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, element

I tried two codes to click on the element using `execute_script` method.
The first one is:

```
element_xpath = '//div[@data-testid="listing-card-title"]' 
target_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", target_element)
```

The second one is:

```
element_xpath = '//div[@data-testid="listing-card-title"]' 
target_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath) 
target_element_coordinates = target_element.location
driver.execute_script("document.elementFromPoint(%s, %s).click();" % (target_element_coordinates['x'], target_element_coordinates['y']))
```

The first one didn't give me an error but also not clicking the element.
The second one works fine why is that so?

Comment: Give more details to this question. Which site are you testing it on, what element, and what kind of output are you expecting. Aim to be a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

### `elementFromPoint()`

The [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) method of the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface returns the topmost element at the specified coordinates.

Syntax:

```
elementFromPoint(x, y)
```

Parameters:

- `x` : The horizontal coordinate of a point, relative to the left edge of the current viewport.
- `y` : The vertical coordinate of a point, relative to the top edge of the current viewport.

Return value: The topmost [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object located at the specified coordinates.

---

### This usecase

Both of the snippets synchronously executes JavaScript in the current window/frame using the [execute_script(script, *args)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) command.

```
element_xpath = '//div[@data-testid="listing-card-title"]' 
target_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", target_element)
```

and

```
element_xpath = '//div[@data-testid="listing-card-title"]' 
target_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath) 
target_element_coordinates = target_element.location
driver.execute_script("document.elementFromPoint(%s, %s).click();" % (target_element_coordinates['x'], target_element_coordinates['y']))
```

The only difference seems there some extra time spent in the second attempt while collecting the location of the  **target_element** using [location](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location) attribute which gets the location of the element in the renderable canvas.

---

### Conclusion

In the first attempt possibly the click on the desired element is obscured by some other element which clears away during your second attempt while collecting the location.